# Realod DataList on Client Side with XmlDataSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hello i want to reload the Datalist on client side  after regular interval of time by using jquery or javscript so as i can get the latest RSS news feed here is my code

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="http://www.example.com/category/test/feed/"
   XPath="rss/channel/item"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:DataList ID="dlRss" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <label style="color: #222222; float: left; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 5px; width: 190px;">
      <%#  XPath("title")%></label>
      <label style="color: #444444; display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; margin-bottom: 5px;
         width: 190px;">
      <%# Convert.ToDateTime(XPath("pubDate")).ToShortDateString() + " @" + Convert.ToDateTime(XPath("pubDate")).ToShortTimeString()%></label>
      <label style="color: #444444; display: inline-block; font-size: 13px; width: 190px;">
      <%#XPath("description").ToString().Length <= 200 ? XPath("description") : XPath("description").ToString().Substring(0,200) + "...<a href='" + XPath("link").ToString() + "' target='_blank'>more</a>"%></label>
      <br />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set `DataSource` at client end.
But what you can do is this `reload` your page after a particular interval.

**Otherwise** you will have to use http handler with jtemplate and jquery.

Here are some links which may help you

http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/18/jtemplates-with-jquery-ajax-and-json/
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=573

Comment: Thanks, i think i should use Json and WedMehtods to bind the DataList, because page is very heavy and i don't want to reload the whole page